# How do I present INNER JOINed SQL data with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I Have three tables, one acting as a "link" to the other two. What i am trying to achieve is this

```
Products
Num|Product_Code   
1  | HVTE  
2  | HVTT 
3  | HV31 
4  | HV11 

Colours
Num|Colour|Image
1   Yellow Yellow Image link
2   Orange Orange Image link
3   Pink   Pink image link

Product-Colours
P_Num | Colour_Num
1       1
1       2
2       1
```

What i am hoping to achieve is that if P_Num = Products.Num and Colour_Num = Colours.Num output the colour images on screen.

I am fairly new to PHP so need quite a thorough explanation if possible.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I don't understand the question, and how is this about algorithms?

Comment: The intermediary table is called an 'association' table.  Also, read up on Primary Key and Foreign Key.  The question does not have anything to do with PHP other than this how you are interpreting the SQL results.

Comment: It is a webpage i am producing using PHP to communicate with a MySQL database. I know what PK and FK's are, what i am trying to achieve is to output the image stored in the "colours" table based on the columns matching.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly what you want is the colours of a product given the product number. What you'd need to do is simply join the association table with the colours table. That is:

```
SELECT 
  Colour
FROM
  Colours
JOIN
  `Product-Colours`
ON
  Colours.Num = `Product-Colours`.Colour_Num
WHERE
  `Product-Colours`.P_Num = # The Product Number
```

Note that using `-` to name a table forces you to quote the table name with backticks... In my opinion this is a little bit annoying so it might be a good idea to rename `Product-Colours` to something like `Product_Colours`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is available by googling, [such as with this page](http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql/4), which was the 1st listing when you search for ["php mysql example"](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+mysql&aq=f&oq=php+mysql).

```
<?php

mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$query = "SELECT  `Image` as prod_colour_img_link FROM  Colours JOIN  `Product-Colours` ON  Colours.Num = `Product-Colours`.Colour_Num WHERE  `Product-Colours`.P_Num = ".$prod_num;

mysql_query($query);

$num=mysql_numrows($result) 

echo '<ol>';
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {  
  $prod_colour_img_link = mysql_result($result,$i,"Colour");

  echo '<li><img src="'.$prod_colour_img_link.'" /></li>';

  $i++;
}
echo '</ol>';

?>
```

You should readable mysql-safe column & table names (naming conventions) as the names you're picking will lead to errors that you'll get headaches debugging.  YOu can use those name, but you shouldn't.

If this answer isn't perfect, please spend some effort modifying it to suit your needs and then present a specific question.